What's the overall algorithm for population evolution in the NEAT algorithm?
I am implementing NEAT from scratch using Ruby, and I'm having a hard time understanding the necessary steps and overall algorithm of what happens between generations.
I have the Genome (made of Nodes and Connections objects) and the Population (made of Species and Genomes objects) classes.
I am able to speciate the genome into species, calculate fitness for each genome/species, average and adjusted fitness, all of that.
But I'm getting stuck in what happens between generations once I have the genome sorted into species.

Should I keep species around between generations? Should I keep their genomes too?
When generating new offspring from species, should I automatically put them in their parent species? If so, how new species will be found? Won't all genome be part of the same first species?
If I use some elitism logic and discard 80% of the lower fitness genomes from each species, how do I fill in the blank? Should I use only crossover from species or should I introduce new "blank" genomes?

I feel like calculating and generating a completely new population between generations is much easier than keeping things between generations and deciding what stays vs what is replaced.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
